# preRenderView method executed before I get to the page

Tags: jsf-2

I've got this in a page I use to edit 'events'

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="event_id" name="eventId" value="#{eventController.eventId}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{eventController.loadEvent}" />
</f:metadata>
```

...and a corresponding loadEvent method in my "ViewScoped" bean.

In a 'list events' page where the user can select which event they want to edit, I build up links like this

```
<h:link value="Full details" outcome="/calendar/viewEvent" includeViewParams="true">
    <f:param name="eventId" value="#{calendarController.event.eventId}" />
</h:link>
```

I wouldn't expect the loadEvent method to be called until I click on a link, but it gets called once, and once only, when I visit the 'list events' page.

Sure this is down to the JSF-lifecycle somehow... but why?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the concrete problem. Are you saying that you've this `<f:metadata>` block in `viewEvent.xhtml`, but that it's already been processed when you just open `listEvents.xhtml`? That's impossible. Are you sure that you're explaining the problem right and/or that you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: Yep, that's what's happening. It doesn't happen the first time after I deploy my application. But any time after that I go to 'listEvents' it calls the loadEvent method on my viewEvent bean! There isn't a single reference to 'viewEventBean' in my listEvents page, but somehow it's still getting called. Are there some known bugs with the latest Mojarra, because I'm getting loads of strange behaviours. As another example, my viewParams, despite following your blogs (and others) instructions, are not working for ViewScoped beans. Loads of simple things just dont seem to work (could be me though!)

Comment: Are those entirely separate views or are it conditionally rendered includes of some common master view?

Comment: They both use the same template but apart from that, yeah they're both separate.

Comment: Still getting this. Any ideas anyone? Bizarre...

Answer (score 3):

I'm also experiencing this with Mojarra 2.1.10 (I'm assuming you're also on Mojarra?). The bug has already been submitted as [JAVASERVERFACES-2158](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2158) with no fix or workaround at the time of writing. The problem is this: During preemptive navigation done when rendering `UIOutcomeTarget` components such as `h:link` and `h:button` *with view parameters included*, the target view is compiled to extract `f:viewParam`/`UIViewParameter` components from its `h:metadata` element. This compilation has a side-effect of also setting up event subscriptions on the *current* `UIViewRoot` based on the `f:event` elements . In the normal case – that is when the view returned to the user in the response is being compiled – this is all fine. However, when another view is compiled for the sake of obtaining its view parameters, registering event subscriptions on the *current* view root (as in `FacesContext.getViewRoot()`) is not fine at all.

Comment: Thanks for this, glad to know I wasn't going crazy. I'll keep an eye on it. I only dip into JSF every now and again (writing some right now actually) and find it a love-hate relationship. It's a superb framework but certainly has its quirks. Now you have pointed me at the JIRA issue I'll keep an eye on it.